# drag and drop Div columns and Div rows using JQuery ui

Tags: jquery-ui

we are creating a table structure using html div, inside that we need to drag and drag and drop the columns and rows , but the row head  should be fixed. ie, Drag and drop Div columns and Div rows without moving row head
anybody knows how to solve this.

I need to create this using JQuery , html and css.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tblcols").sortable({
    items: '.rtab:not(.rtab:first-child)',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    axis: 'y',
    dropOnEmpty: false,
    start: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.addClass("selected");
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.removeClass("selected");
      $(this).find(".rtab").each(function(index) {
        if (index > 0) {
          $(this).find(".ctab").eq(2).html(index);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.Table {
  display: table;
}

.Title {
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
}

.Heading {
  display: table-row;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.rtab {
  display: table-row;
}

.ctab {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.htab {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="Table">
  <div class="Title">
    <p>Drag table rows and columns</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Heading">
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Sl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Designation</p>
    </div>
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Salary</p>
    </div>
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Location</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rtab" id="tblcols">
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Athira</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Developer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>6l</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Kottayam</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rtab">
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Timy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Designer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>5l</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>wayanad</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rtab">
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Liya</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Team Lead</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>7l</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Kollam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're mixing a lot of libraries. I would pick one jQuery and one version of jQuery UI. So instead of CSS from 1.8.24, use the css from the same version of jQuery UI 1.10.2. This example doesn't seem to work for Sortable when I test it. Is this the code you're using? Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Thank you. Yes. its works for me and row can drag and drop. i need the column also. and no errors in my console.

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unsure what you mean. I hope I captured the main idea, that you want the first cell in each row to remain in order after items are sorted. Here is an example that might work for you.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".Table .Heading").sortable({
    items: '> .htab:not(:eq(0))',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    axis: 'x',
    dropOnEmpty: false,
    placeholder: "htab placeholder",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      var ind = ui.item.index();
      $(".Table .rtab").each(function() {
        $(".ctab", this).eq(ind).css("opacity", "0.25");
      });
      ui.item.data("orig-index", ind);
    },
    stop: function() {
      $(".Table .rtab .ctab").css("opacity", "");
    },
    update: function(e, ui) {
      var oInd = ui.item.data("orig-index");
      var cInd = ui.item.index();
      var cols = $(".Table .htab").length;

      $(".Table .rtab").each(function() {
        var cell = $(".ctab", this).eq(oInd).detach();
        if (cInd < (cols - 1)) {
          // Mid Col
          cell.insertBefore($(".ctab", this).eq(cInd));
        } else {
          // Last Col
          $(this).append(cell);
        }
      })
    }
  });
  $(".Table").sortable({
    items: '> .rtab',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    axis: 'y',
    dropOnEmpty: false,
    start: function(e, ui) {
      $(".ctab", ui.item).eq(0).html("&nbsp;");
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(".Table .rtab").each(function(ind, el) {
        $(".ctab", el).eq(0).html((ind + 1));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.Table {
  display: table;
}

.Title {
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
}

.Heading {
  display: table-row;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.rtab {
  display: table-row;
}

.ctab {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.htab {
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.htab.placeholder {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="Table">
  <div class="Title">
    <p>Drag table rows and columns</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Heading">
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Sl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Designation</p>
    </div>
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Salary</p>
    </div>
    <div class="htab">
      <p>Location</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rtab" id="tblcols">
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Athira</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Developer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>6l</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Kottayam</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rtab">
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Timy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Designer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>5l</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>wayanad</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rtab">
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Liya</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Team Lead</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>7l</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ctab">
      <p>Kollam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

For the Header, we can sort the header items and then move the cells that correspond with it. Due to the relationship of the elements in Rows, there is not an element that contains all the column items. It effectively does what is needed, yet looks a little weird in doing it. With `items` we can exclude the first header.

When using Sortable for the Rows, you want to target the parent and then using `items` option, you can target the rows that you want to sort and those you want to exclude. Since we're sorting the rows and not the items inside, there is not a good way to exclude an item in the row.

When Sort starts, cell 0 is change to `&nbsp;` so it does not shrink too much. Once sort is stopped, it re-indexes the rows back into order. If we use `update` it will only fire when a change is performed. So if the user grabs a row and doesn't move it, there is not `update`. To address this, we can use `stop` to re-index.

Hope that helps.

Comment: and there is small correction if we are using fiest column as text field it replaces to serial numbers. so i have changed that script for row drag and drop to my previous script. . Thank you !!!